# How to find papers from conference proceedings?

Tags: publications, literature-search

I'm starting out in a new field, and reading papers from top conferences in the field seemed as a natural starting point to understanding active research areas in the field. I realized I have never really searched for papers from a conference before, instead I've searched only by keyword. Any way to go about this?

Comment: Did you try Googling for "AwesomeConf 2017 proceedings"?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest a [three-step **easy**](https://www.reddit.com/r/AntiJokes/comments/2odrr8/what_are_the_three_steps_to_put_an_elephant_into/) solution:

1. Open the Web page of a search engine in your browser, type in the name of the conference you are interested in, and click the search button.
2. Go to the Web site of the conference.
3. Find the name of the publisher on the Web site of the conference, go the Web page of the publisher, and search for the papers from the conference proceedings there.

This solution has an advantage of being **universal** and might require small adjustments on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score -1):

1 - Talk to your supervisors or professors in your department and they will tell you which conference proceedings are more relevant to your specific area.

2 - Check with your university if you have an online-portal area that allows you to search for conference proceedings that you would otherwise have to pay for. Universities, in general I think, provide access to all their enrolled students to various institutions. For example, if you are a Computing Science student, your University might get you access to the digital libraries of ACM and IEEE.

3 - Use tools such as Google Scholar

4 - When you come across an interesting paper, look at the references.